# Ruby on Rails: I need some help designing a gem that will help centralize permissions throughout the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So, me app is pretty large, and I'm working on minimizing code. One thing that has been bothering me is how every time we need to check to see if a user can do something, we need to have the same if statements in multiple locations within the app's code.  I've looked at some gems that supposedly handle permissions and roles and such, but none of them seem adequate for the level of control that I need.

Basically, all permissions are based off 4 things:

1. current_user
2. current_account
3. current_account_permissions # bunch of boolean values for what the account can/can't do
4. the object we are currently dealing with

Now, the first 3 are never going to change during a session (in most cases anyway), so if there would be away to store these in the gem only once somehow, that would be baller.

So, my vision for how defining (simple) methods after having the completed gem installed looks kind of like this:

```
can edit_content?(content) do
    if (current_user.role >= User::MANAGER or content.user_id == current_user.id)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

and then, in my view, something like this:

```
<% if can :edit_content?(content) %>
...
<% end >
```

So, this gem would be a little (auth system must use current_user, current_account) specific to my app's setup, but I think the idea of a gem is the best way to go about solving the duplicate permissions check issue.

All help is appreciated. Thanks! =D

Answer (score 1):

It's been done, and done well. Recommend you have a look at the CanCan gem: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: The CanCan gem only allows permissions for actions / methods in controllers and models. This is not what I want to do. I need custom booleans that I can define and access throughout both controllers and views. If CanCan can (lol) do that, then documentation would be wonderful. But as far as I can tell, they only allow the can :my_permission_here definitions which are accessible through views.

Comment: also, I need access to the current_account helper. CanCan needs to be able to be aware of more than just current_user =\

Comment: On first item, you can create methods in your controllers utilizing CanCan and then expose them to your views via a call to helper_method. On second item, assuming a user is attached to an account, could you not access current_user.account? If not then I'm sure you could fork CanCan and add that in. In any event, if you find that you cannot use CanCan, tweaked or otherwise, then at least you can inspect the code and likely find answers to most of your "how do I?" questions.

Comment: I'll fork it. Might be a decent place to start.